# PHP HTTP POST gets "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."

Tags: php, curl, encoding

Why doesn't this PHP-7 code snippet work properly?

```
    $json = json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL                 => '...',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER      => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER      => false,
        CURLOPT_POST                => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $json,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8',
                                            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
                                        ),
    ));
```

Google's API complains: *"This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."*

But, what is the correct PHP-foo to specify the encoding that Google wants?

Comment: Similar to post #22960125.  I added `CURLOPT_HEADER` with values of both 0 and 1 to no good effect.  I know that I am just shooting in the dark here ...

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you have non-UTF8 encoded string?

This guy seems to have the same problem https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-content-api-for-shopping/5I8MHpfbH4A

Comment: I saw that one, but no.  It's an ordinary ASCII string with no special characters in it at all.  The problem in that post appeared to be that the encoder was returning `false`, but  I have confirmed that the `json_encode()` function returns a valid JSON string.  The problem here appears to be the encoding, and PHP's documentation is not at all clear on the subject of encoding.

Comment: I'm not familiar with postman.  I do see this comment in the PHP docs for CURL:  "Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as `multipart/form-data`, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`."  In both cases it refers to "`form-`." (The page URL is http://php.net//manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and the comment is at the bottom of that page.)

Comment: I'm not too keen on "dumpster-diving" into Google's official PHP API, which consists of *over seven thousand(!)* PHP files!

Comment: Can you try to add "Accept: application/json" to the header?

Comment: Also which API are you calling? Can you write the url and the params ?

Comment: This is the Google Shopping API.  `Accept:` as-expected had no useful effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170795/discussion-between-alessandro-vegna-and-mike-robinson).

Comment: I'm not trying to chat about this – I'm simply searching for an answer, and trying to avoid `grep`ping through 7,000 source files to find the magic `CURLOPT_` voodoo.  All that can be said about the description of the problem has already been said in this ticket.  The root cause problem *is* the encoding – and other APIs besides this one have the same characteristic.  There must be some combination of `CURLOPT`s that is magically correct.

Comment: I was just trying to help. In this case since you think is an encoding/CURL problem, as I said, download postman, is really straight forward, try to do the same call and check if it works, if yes is a CURL problem, if not is your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Well, I found it!!**

The subroutine which actually invokes the CURL call *(not shown)* issued its own `curl_setopt` of `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, apparently superseding the option settings shown here.

The code that works looks like this: *(with `$headers` being merged with a few other headers by the CURL-call routine, also not shown here, via `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`)*.

```
    $json = json_encode($data);
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
        'Accept: application/json'
        );
    curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL                 => '...',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER      => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER      => false,
        CURLOPT_POST                => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $json,
    ));
```

So, I *was* trying "the right PHP mojo," but failed to realize that some of the options weren't being set – that is, the settings didn't "stick" – because of another bug in my program which was never shown on this ticket.

Now we know:  if you use these CURL options, *and* include these headers *(`Accept:` is actually up to you ...)*, and be sure that `CURL_POSTFIELDS` is a string not an array, it will work. Whereas, if you do *not* do all of these things, cryptic messages will be the result.